# Constructing a Borel-measurable function from a semi-analytic one

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

Consider a function $f: X \rightarrow (0, \infty)$ whose domain $X$ is a [standard Borel space](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Standard_Borel_space). Suppose $f$ is *upper semi-analytic*, i.e. for every $\lambda \geq 0$ the set $\{x \in X : f(x) > \lambda\}$ is [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_set).

**Question:** Is it possible to construct a non-negative real-valued function $g$ on $X$ such that $f+g$ is [Borel-measurable](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Borel_function)?

**Thoughts:** Let $\mathbb{Q}$ denote the set of all rational numbers. Since $x \in X$ satisfies $f(x) + g(x) > \lambda$ if and only if there exists a $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ satisfying $f(x) > q > \lambda - g(x)$, we can write

$$
\{x \in X : f(x) + g(x) > \lambda\} = \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}}\{x \in X : f(x) > q\}\cap\{x \in X : g(x) > \lambda - q\}.
$$

So, $f+g$ would be Borel-measurable if the sets $\{x \in X : f(x) > q\} \cap \{x \in X : g(x) > \lambda - q\}$ are all Borel. Note that, since $f$ is upper semi-analytic, the sets $\{x \in X : f(x) > q\}$ are analytic.

Comment: Without some additional constraints on the function $g$, the answer to your question is "Yes, trivially": simply take $g=-f$.

Comment: Good point, thanks John. The question has been updated.

Comment: The problem persists: If $f$ is bounded above by the constant $b$, then $g:=b-f$ is non-negative and $f+g=b$ is constant, hence Borel.

Comment: Ah, thanks again John! Actually, I asked this question because I thought it might be useful for answering a different question, which I care more about. I'm going to post that one shortly, but now I'm curious whether the present question is still trivial if $f$ isn't bounded.